# Split text in hash value into new hash using separator in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-hash

I found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50598509/how-to-separate-two-data-in-one-cell-on-csv-by-ruby) similar to the one I have, but I was not able to replicate it (probably because it doesn't deal with hashes neither have symbols).

So, given the following array of hashes:

```
[{:id=>1, :name=>"AA;AB;AC", :title=>"A row"},
 {:id=>2, :name=>"BA;BB", :title=>"B row"},
 {:id=>3, :name=>"CA", :title=>"C row"}]
```

I would like to achieve the following result:

```
[{:id=>1, :name=>"AA", :title=>"A row"},
 {:id=>1, :name=>"AB", :title=>"A row"},
 {:id=>1, :name=>"AC", :title=>"A row"},
 {:id=>2, :name=>"BA", :title=>"B row"},
 {:id=>2, :name=>"BB", :title=>"B row"},
 {:id=>3, :name=>"CA", :title=>"C row"}]
```

In brief, I want to fully replicate a hash, splitting it by semicolon. In this case, `:name` have two hashes with one or more semicolons that should be split and consist on another hash.

I hope you have understand my question. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I tried the approach that is on the another question link, without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate over your array of hashes and split their `name` value, and map that result merging it with the current hash. Then you can flatten the result:

```
[
  {:id=>1, :name=>"AA;AB;AC", :title=>"A row"},
  {:id=>2, :name=>"BA;BB", :title=>"B row"},
  {:id=>3, :name=>"CA", :title=>"C row"}
].flat_map do |hsh|
  hsh[:name].split(";").map do |name|
    hsh.merge(name: name)
  end
end

# [{:id=>1, :name=>"AA", :title=>"A row"},
#  {:id=>1, :name=>"AB", :title=>"A row"},
#  {:id=>1, :name=>"AC", :title=>"A row"},
#  {:id=>2, :name=>"BA", :title=>"B row"},
#  {:id=>2, :name=>"BB", :title=>"B row"},
#  {:id=>3, :name=>"CA", :title=>"C row"}]
```

Comment: I had never seen this `flat_map` method before! This is great to flatten the iteration! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object)

```
ary =
  [
    { id: 1, name: "AA;AB;AC", title: "A row" },
    { id: 2, name: "BA;BB", title: "B row" },
    { id: 3, name: "CA", title: "C row" }
  ]

ary.each_with_object([]) do |hash, new_ary|
  hash[:name].split(";").each do |name|
    new_ary << hash.merge(name: name)
  end
end
```